# Fail to jump from a portrait view to a landscape view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, rotation

Everyone. I've got two views. The first view supports only landscape orientation and the second view supports all orientations. However, when the second view is portrait and a button is pressed, it jumps to the first one portrait, which is meant to be landscape.

I've added the following two method in the first ViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
        return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

I wonder if anyone could help me, since this issue had puzzled me for long. 
Thanks in forward!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that whether i got u correctly or not. upto what i got is that you have 2 viewControllers, first viewController supports only Landscape while 2nd viewController supports all Orientations. But you r having problem in maintaining this. Check whether you have implemented this in your code, if u still find any problem, do revert back and if it solves kindly Accept the answer and vote it up too ;) :-

1) Your first viewController should have this :-
// for iOS 6

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

for < iOS 6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);

}
```

2) Your second viewController Should have this:-
for iOS 6

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

for < iOS6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: I tried your method, but unfortunately it didn't work. When I jumped from the second view portrait back to the first view, the device is portrait while the view is landscape...

Comment: I think u must have the first view elements in Portrait mode.?? did you.??

Comment: Give me your email Id i have made an app for you according to your requirement. And yeah do accept my answer and vote up please.

Comment: I do want to vote up for u, however, I'm a freshman here and don't have enough reputation to vote up. sorry for this. My email is 995967851@qq.com. Thanks so much for your patience.

Comment: Its fyn, you can accept the answer if it helps.Check your mail.

Comment: I've received your app and it works exactly as what I need. While I compared my app with yours and only to find no difference, mine just doesn't work as I need...I've accepted your answer and thanks again.

Comment: Thanks :), as you are a newbie, i think i know where you have done the mistakes. i too have gone through this situation. Keep it up. Just tell me if i can you :), Adios

Comment: I'm so lucky to have met you in such a short time here. Keep contact and hope everything goes well. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had never tested this in an application but try to use:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

Comment: It warned me: 'UIDevice' may not respond to 'setOrientation'...and I try to fix it into [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft; I got an error of "Assignment to readonly property"....

Comment: What iOS you are developing for?

Comment: An iPad app. The autorotation issue has puzzled me for long and I'm close to be crazy about it...